# Android Camera Landscape to Portrait orientation issue

Tags: android, camera, orientation, landscape, portrait

I am having trouble with Camera orientation in Android application. It is showing landscape all the time. I dont see `camera.setDisplayOrientation(90)` option in the project. I am using Android SDK 2.1.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setRotation(90);       
parameters.setPictureSize(640, 480);
this.camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

This didn't help either. Please any one have any idea what I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would let your camera orientation always be Landscape.  The Android Camera app locks the Activity orientation to Landscape, because that is the natural orientation of the camera sensor (this is true for all compatible Android devices).  But it writes the detected device rotation into the EXIF so that a viewer application can display the photo properly.